# webContents.send vs webContents.executeJavaScript

Tags: javascript, ipc, electron

My web app uses `ipcRender.send` to ask listening electron `ipcMain.on` for a value from the system. The process is asynchronous, so once the electron get's the value from the system, it then inits a call back to the app. What is the cleaner approach to pass the value? What approach should I use and why?

---

#### webContents.send

*listen on event*

app

```
window.myFunction = data => setState(data)
ipcRenderer.on('my-function', (ev, data) => window.myFunction(data));
```

electron

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('my-function', value)
```

---

#### webContents.executeJavaScript

*function call*

app

```
window.myFunction = data => setState(data)
```

electron

```
mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`myFunction(${data});`)
```

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main difference is that `ipcRenderer.on` is more flexible and scalable, because it lets you use `ipcRenderer` module which is an instance of `EventEmitter`. It can add, remove listeners (subscribers). It also lets you send both - synchronous and asynchronous messages.

`webContents.executeJavaScript` from what I found, just lets you remove limitations from some HTML APIs methods that can only be invoked by a gesture from the user.

For ex. `requestFullScreen`:

```
webContents.executeJavaScript(code[, userGesture])
```

Setting `userGesture` to `true` will remove this limitation.

[webContents](https://xwartz.gitbooks.io/electron-gitbook/content/en/api/web-contents.html)

Comment: API of executeJavaScript would have same API on CEF Platform. If the application want to go true native direction, if it is a success and require more native performance and natural interaction. I am no sure whether C++ CEF, or other language have similar API of webContents.send. As half of the interaction of Web from native, would be loading a page and executeJavascript, another half might be response the action on the Web toward OS native action. Anyway, great answer